# Как узнать сколько дней было в прошлом месяце? 30 или 31

Tags: java, calendar

Мне нужно получить количество дней в прошлом месяце. Я знаю как получить количество дней в этом месяце. Вот так: `int dayOfMnthMax = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`
Но мне нужно в прошлом месяце.

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать задачу более внятно. Что такое "максимальное количество дней в прошлом месяце"? Какое максимальное количество дней в прошлом месяце июле и чем оно отличается от простого количества дней в июле, которое равно 31?

Comment: Смотрите, бывает что в одних месяцах 30 дней, а в других 31. Мне нужно узнать, сколько дней было в прошлом месяце. Теперь понятно?)

Comment: Установите `Calendar` на прошлый месяц и считайте - в чем собственно проблема то?

Comment: @mr.hinkal05 понятно. А причём тут слово "максимальное"?

Comment: Нууу, если получить максимальное количество дней в прошлом месяце. Я же узнаю сколько дней было в прошлом месяце)) 30 или 31

Comment: Вы знаете как мне узнать сколько дней было в прошлом месяце? Я изменил вопрос)

Comment: Взять первое число следующего месяца, отнять сутки, посмотреть день.

Comment: не нужно добавлять к вопросу android studio. Вопрос не относится к АС вообще никак.

Comment: Мне тут написали "Установите Calendar на прошлый месяц и считайте" а как узнать какой месяц был прошлым??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так предлагают сделать в комментариях выше ( Barmaley Red Star ).

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

    int max = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Взяв такое на вооружение можно вычислять что угодно

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!